# VTD-XML: Only closing tag check is not working

Tags: xml, vtd-xml

I'm Using VTD-XML parser to get the value from XML with path given. Below my java code.

```
VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
vg.setDoc(xml.getBytes());
vg.parse(true);
VTDNav vn = vtdGen.getNav();
AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
xpath="ROOT/STUDENT[(not(DATE) or DATE='')]/NAME";
ap.selectXPath(xpath);

while(ap.evalXPath() != -1) {
        long l = vn.getContentFragment();
        value= vn.toString((int )l, (int)(l>>32));
}
```

And my xml look like this.

```
<ROOT>
<STUDENT>
    <NAME>John</NAME>
    <DATE>12-JUNE-18</DATE>
</STUDENT>
<STUDENT>
    <NAME>Peter</NAME>
    <DATE/>
</STUDENT>
</ROOT>
```

I wanted to select the name peter using the XPATH. This xpath is working in xsl transformation, but is not working in VTD-XML.

Am i doing anything wrong with my parsing or XPATH?

Answer (score 0):

When you finished parsing xml with VTD-XML, the default cursor position for the VTDNav is at the root element node. In your case, it is at ROOT node. So when you run the xpath "ROOT/STUDENT[(not(DATE) or DATE='')]/NAME", you are actually querying
/ROOT/ROOT/STUDENT/NAME node.

The easiest correction is to change XPath to STUDENT[(not(DATE) or DATE='')]/NAME, which is a relative xpath.

Or you can use an absolute xpath /ROOT/STUDENT[(not(DATE) or DATE='')]/NAME.

Or you can first call VTDNav's toElement() method and give it a "PARENT" parameter to move the cursor to the document node... it will work too

After a few testing on my end, I discover that this is a bug in a method inside VTDNav class called

XPathStringVal_Matches(int j, String s);

Will you be comfortable with cutting/pasting some code to rectify the bug?

I will provide you with instruction, very simple to fix...

Comment: Still not able to select Peter, if I give suggested XPath 'STUDENT[(not(DATE) or DATE='')]/NAME', the problem is closing tag.

Comment: Thanks.. Easiest fix i did was to change the xpath to 'STUDENT[(not(DATE) or DATE='') or DATE[not(text())] ]/NAME'. And it is working, but I found another problem if i want to select date with end tag /ROOT/STUDENT[NAME='PETER']/DATE getting the java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Comment: if an xpath eval returns a -1, you should catch that condition. VTD index of -1 is probly causing the exception.

Comment: Thanks..yeah I got that.. but that shouldn't be handled in API and returning the empty string. Because empty closing tag like <DATE></DATE> works perfectly.